# How to Creatcustom Counters in Hadoop 2.0.3 alpha

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop.I am trying to write a custom counter in my reducer.I found a example of using custom counters but it was in hadoop 1.x. I dont find any proper solution for counters in hadoop 2.x
  Can anyone help me on this issue..?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

by looking at the code of 2.x I believe it works in just the same way as the examples of earlier releases

The counters are maintained by org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounters

The findCounter generates a new counter on the fly when there is a request for a counter which is not already in the cache

```
  public synchronized C findCounter(Enum<?> key) {
    C counter = cache.get(key);
    if (counter == null) {
      counter = findCounter(key.getDeclaringClass().getName(), key.name());
      cache.put(key, counter);
    }
    return counter;
  }
```

( it uses the Enum class name as the group name for the counters defined by this enum )

And the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Context object that is passed to the map and reduce methods implements the getCounter(Enum) method